# WPF: hide Listview item defined using GridviewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating an application to show a list of windows services not running. the problem is that those services should reflect any changes  occurring, that is if a service starts, that service should be removed from the displayed list.

I used a ListView, here is the code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:NotifiableServiceController}"
    MethodName="GetServices" x:Key="ManageServices">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView Name="lstViewServices" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ManageServices}}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="SoftOne Services" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and the function getting the service List:

```
public static ObservableCollection<NotifiableServiceController> GetServices()
        {
            ObservableCollection<NotifiableServiceController> oaServices = new ObservableCollection<NotifiableServiceController>();

            //Retrieving the services starting with "SQL"
            foreach (ServiceController sc in ServiceController.GetServices().Where(p => p.DisplayName.StartsWith("SQL")))
            {
                oaServices.Add(new NotifiableServiceController(sc));
            }

            return oaServices;
        }
```

The `NotifiableServiceController` is being updated at time interval to refresh the status of the associated Windows service. But only the first-time retrieved services (from `GetServices()` function) will be refreshed.

That is all fine till now. **I just need to have only stopped processes displayed in the Listview** and I think that can be done using Style or Triggers in XAML? if yes, how?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a style to the ListView and targetting the ListViewItem as follow:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Running">
                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Depending of the Service `Status`, I can take set the visibility and the Height of the ListViewItem

Answer (score 1):

I think that you shoud use **ListCollectioView**, and filter it using **Filter** property. First, you have to load all the servicies, and than you can update it every N seconds using a **Timer.Elapsed** event.

Comment: thanks, that is a potential solution but setting the ListCollectionView would require me to change a lot of code, please find my answer to see how I solved it

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the running services from the `ObservableCollection<NotifiableServiceController>` you bound your `ListView` against and add it back whenever a service stopped. If you want to keep a collection of **all** services, create an extra collection for that.